# symfony 2.3 Call to a member function get() on a non-object in __construct function

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, security-context

My project runs on symfony 2.3 with fosuserbundle.
I want to get the current user in the controller

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$this->currentUser = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
```

and it works if I do it in `indexAction()`.
But i need the user in every function of the controller so I tried putting the code in a `__construct` function and now it doesn't work anymore.

Why can't I set the variable in a construct function?

Comment: $this->getUser() is all you need.  Take a look at the S2 base controller class.  You will notice that it has no constructor and that the container is injected later on with a setContainer method.  Which explains why putting this sort of code in the constructor will not work.  But again, the existing getUser method means you don't need to use the consturcor anyways,

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the construct function use:

```
return $this->redirect('login');
```

Do not use:

```
   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));
```

So it should like this:

```
   class DefaultController extends Controller
   {
     public function __construct()
     {
           return $this->redirect('login');
           exit;

     }

      /**
      * @Route("/", name="home")
      */
     public function indexAction(Request $request)
      {

      }
   }
```